# Intersection of two lists by object property

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream, intersection

If I have two lists of objects, I can find the intersection as follows:

```
public class MyObject {
     String id;
     String someField;
     String someOtherField;
}

List<MyObject> list1;
List<MyObject> list2;

List<MyObject> intersect = list1.stream()
                           .filter(list2::contains)
                           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a similar way to find the intersection based on the `id` field of `MyObject`? I can't override the equals method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similarly to Eran's answer above but perhaps with slightly more efficiency you could pull the IDs out into a separate Set first:

```
Set<String> ids = list2.stream().map(obj -> obj.id).collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<MyObject> intersect = list1.stream()
    .filter(obj -> ids.contains(obj.id))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The reason this would be more efficient is that for each item in `list1` you can determine if the ID is in `list2` in O(1) time so overally your runtime is O(list1 + list2)

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
List<MyObject> intersect =
    list1.stream()
         .filter(obj1 -> list2.stream().map(MyObject::getId).anyMatch(id -> id.equals(obj1.getId()))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course, if two `MyObject` instances having the same id are considered identical, you can implement an `equals` method that returns `true` if and only if the ids are the same, and then your original code will suffice.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this approach. But I don't think it would be good for performance:

```
List<MyObject> intersect = list1.stream()
                       .filter(l1 -> list2.stream().anyMatch(l2 -> l2.id.equals(l1.id)))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the `ids` to a `Set`, so that the lookups are as fast as possible:

```
Set<String> inclusionsSet = list2.stream().map(a -> a.id()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<String> intersection = list1.stream().filter(a -> inclusionsSet.contains(a)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```